# Why my iOS app fails / closes when I open it from iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ios-simulator

I am developing a small Swift application. In Xcode, when I press `run` button or use `cmd + R` keyboard shortcut, simulator and my app runs as I expected. But in simulator, when I click my installed app's icon to run it my app appears for one second and crashes / fails with no error message or no log.

I'm new to iOS development and don't know is this a common issue or where I do wrong.

I've reset simulator content and settings by `iOS Simulator Menu -> Reset Content and Settings...` option.

I've restarted iOS simulator, Xcode and operating system (OS X) but the problem still existing.

I basically want to click my installed app's icon in simulator and run it. How can I fix this issue?

--

**Edit due comments:**

I don't touch `AppDelegate.swift` file. It is same as first generated. And I have only one ViewController class, `ViewController.swift` and methods are:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        login()
    }

    /// Login method
    func login() {
       // login methos's body
    }
```

Comment: How did you close your app the first time? Is the debugger still attached?

Comment: Do the Reset Content remove your application from the simulator? If not, remove it from the simulator then install it again by Xcode.

Comment: I've tried two way. 1-> To press the stop (`Stop the running schema or application`) button and 2 -> In simulator, double press `cmd + Shift + H` keyboard combination and swipe the application to upside of the simulator. Both two way are same result.

Comment: @tyt_g207 Yes it removes. I also try to remove it manually and deploy it again. Result: same.

Comment: there might be some issue in the viewDidLoad method or AppDelegate methods of your project, if you can please update the above question with your appdelegate code and viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear that would be helpful to solve the issue

Comment: This link (at its bottom) has information about finding crash logs for apps in the simulator.  You might check whether you have any.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've got solution. Thanks to @Phillip Mills for his comment. That comment helps me to find solution.

In `System Log Queries`, I found the report crash, like as follow:

```
Dyld Error Message:

 Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/79ECB6DD-8AF9-42F7-8543-AF9F689258C0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/126E829F-A5D3-48CE-B65A-C06CE811A679/MyAwesoneApp.app/MyAwesoneApp
  Reason: image not found
```

And googled it, than found this issue from github:  [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire on my iPhone(iOS8) while debuging #101](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/101)

I tried that I saw from screen shot and it works!

I forgot to add `Alamofire` framework to `Link Binary With Libraries` part.